# How can the "Clear The Whole Game Field" challenge be completed?

Tags: atomas

Am I missing something here or does the game present some different particles after a while which can clear all the present atoms plus the next atom?

Answer (score 1):

The minus atom (spawns at least every 20 moves) can be used to absorb an atom from the circle.

If you happen to get a minus atom when there's only one atom on the circle, you can absorb that and win the challenge.

Comment: After asking this question I did somehow complete this challenge but don't know how and when I did it. I'll check what you're saying to see it for myself.